# Open Another App with android.intent.action.VIEW

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to open another app and open a specific page in it!
in their guide they said to use the bellow for default action

```
android.intent.action.VIEW
```

and use a kind of intent, which didn't get which, like bellow to go to that specific page:

```
somecompany://details?id=com.example.calendar
```

but i don't know how!
And i tryed a ton of solutions but coudn't do it !

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for. This will open a specific app's page in the Google Play store.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(
    "market://details?id=com.mycompany.mypackage")));
```

Don't replace the word market. That is specifically reserved by Android to open the Google Play store.

Comment: does we need any permission to do this in android version 6

Comment: @suvojit_007 You don’t need INTERNET permission to open intents to URLs. The intent is not opened by your own application.

Answer (score 2):

You can launch an app using intents. But to go to a specific page in the app, there should be a pre defined intent to reach there. Either it can be custom intent defined by that app and exposed to others or may be predefined system app. For example, you can open Settings application and reach a particular page in it based on the intents "Setting Application" has defined. Another example is "Camera Application". You can launch it and reach some page in it but not all pages.

In your case you may try something like this though:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
```

I hope you understand what I meant.

Comment: I understand, but all information they gave me was just above two lines !
Actually I want to open my app's page in that app!
that app is an google play alternative, i want users to go to that page and rate my app !
how can I do that ?!

Comment: In that case while launching any application, you can also mention data while launching if that app is meant for that. for example :  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");

Comment: Through the example in above comment, I assume that I need to launch a streaming app. So, I also provide the uri to open in that app. Similarly, You can add your app link in intent.setDataAndType

Comment: Happy that it worked for you :). You can accept the answer, so that it is easy for others to know the correct answer :)